# Split text in file with python

Tags: python, file, annotations

I'm writing a script that split text in file to sequence and write new file , how can i split contents file like this ?
I want to convert annotation from CASIA annotation to label texts by creating new labels

```
S1248R05.jpg 157 161 104

S1248R05.jpg 157 161 104

S1248R06.jpg 168 190 106

S1248R06.jpg 168 190 106

S1248R07.jpg 158 183 105

S1248R07.jpg 158 183 105
```

Output should like this:

```
S1248R05.jpg

157 161 104

S1248R05.jpg

157 161 104

S1248R06.jpg

168 190 106

S1248R06.jpg 

168 190 106

S1248R07.jpg 

158 183 105

S1248R07.jpg 

158 183 105
```

Here is my script:

```py
    with open(r"C:\Users\Abdou\Downloads\Compressed\CASIA Iris V3 Interval\CASIAInterval.txt") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        print(contents)
        result = [re.sub(r'([A-Z]+\g)', r'\n\1', contents).lstrip() for line in f]
        print(result)
        file = open("testfile.txt","w") 
        str1= ''.join(str(result))
        file.write(str(str1))
```

And here is my output:

```
    S1240L04.jpg 129 204 97
    S1240L05.jpg 158 154 95
    S1241R01.jpg 168 148 107
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename) as infile, open("testfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
    data = []
    for line in infile.readlines():
        line = line.strip().split()
        data.append(line[0]+"\n")
        data.append(" ".join(line[1:])+"\n")
    outfile.writelines(data)
```

**Output:**

```
S1248R05.jpg
157 161 104
S1248R05.jpg
157 161 104
S1248R06.jpg
168 190 106
S1248R06.jpg
168 190 106
S1248R07.jpg
158 183 105
S1248R07.jpg
158 183 105
```

Comment: thanks , that work fine , i need to get only numbers like 157 161 104 in new file , every line of numbers should be in file , i will try to code this